# The Equation for solving Matrix is stiffnessmatrix.d == F

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

The Equation for solving Matrix is stiffnessmatrix.d == F. Where I know the Matrix {d} and [F] but [ stiffnessmatrix] is an 18x18 matrix contain 8 variable i need to solve for. Can anyone provide code to solve this.
Mathematica file is here.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t0aBpL_LVgWcUnxX4sXRRXhyS5WlHuoU

Comment: Welcome to out site, then, please don't post screenshot or [attach notebook in your question](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1863/1871).You can check [this post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/1871) to learn how to post your code properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Using the definitions from your notebook.*

As the coeffients `Subscript[EI, i]` appear only linearly, you may try a least squares fit as follows:

```
u = Subscript[K, global].d /. {Subscript[he, 1] -> 1, 
    Subscript[he, 2] -> 1, Subscript[he, 3] -> 0.5, 
    Subscript[he, 4] -> 0.5, Subscript[he, 5] -> 0.5, 
    Subscript[he, 6] -> 0.5, Subscript[he, 7] -> 1, 
    Subscript[he, 8] -> 1};
A = D[
   u,
   {Table[Subscript[EI, i], {i, 1, 8}], 1}
   ];

coeffs = LeastSquares[A, F]
```

However, this will throw an error because you defined `F` as $17 \times 1$-matrix while `Subscript[K, global].d` is a $18 \times 1$-matrix. So your `F` is too short.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Henrik Schumacher. That was my mistake. The [F] should  be 18 X 1 - matrix.

Comment: You're welcome.